# npm won't let me publish even after I have logged in

Tags: github, npm

When I try `git push --follow-tags origin master && npm publish` it ends with

```
npm notice name:          @hoodedunicorn/arduinohc05app
npm notice version:       0.1.12
npm notice filename:      hoodedunicorn-arduinohc05app-0.1.12.tgz
npm notice package size:  6.4 MB
npm notice unpacked size: 24.1 MB
npm notice shasum:        d151f64e3e5a487e8c30e59b72119864ac6f0d7a
npm notice integrity:     sha512-enKDkj0kplQwx[...]rq5Qjlm4Wpyvg==
npm notice total files:   497
npm notice
npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH
npm ERR! need auth This command requires you to be logged in to https://npm.pgk.github.com/
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using npm adduser

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\yadayada\mydebug.log
```

Okay I thought, no biggie just add user.

```
npm adduser --auth-type=legacy
npm notice Log in on https://npm.pkg.github.com/
Username: hoodedunicorn
Password:
Email: (this IS public) emailfor@stackoverflow.com
Logged in on https://npm.pkg.github.com/.

npm whoami
HoodedUnicorn
```

then log in

```
npm login --scope=@HoodedUnicorn --auth-type=legacy --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
npm notice Log in on https://npm.pkg.github.com/
Username: hoodedunicorn
Password:
Logged in to scope @HoodedUnicorn on https://npm.pkg.github.com/.
```

Okay, everything seems good. Let's try that command again in the beginning
`git push --follow-tags origin master && npm publish`

```
npm notice total files:   497
npm notice
npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH
npm ERR! need auth This command requires you to be logged in to https://npm.pgk.github.com/
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using npm adduser`

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\yadayada\mydebug1.log
```

So I try again

```
npm adduser --scope=@HoodedUnicorn --auth-type=legacy --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
npm notice Log in on https://npm.pkg.github.com/
Username: hoodedunicorn
Password:
Email: (this IS public) emailfor@stackoverflow.com
Logged in to scope @HoodedUnicorn on https://npm.pkg.github.com/.

git push --follow-tags origin master && npm publish
```

Same error, `npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using npm adduser`
but
`npm whoami` returns
`HoodedUnicorn`
What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Run `npm login --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com` to login before publishing
  *[**Note:** Make sure you have created a git access token with scopes: `write:packages,repo,delete:packages` or [click here](https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=write:packages,repo,delete:packages) to create a new token]*
- Run `npm whoami` if you are not there then run `npm adduser --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=<token-from-npm>` to add yourself as a publisher

Follow the steps here: [Github NPM Package Registry > Publish](https://gist.github.com/AfzalSabbir/e3a729413ba780e12f6a8ade3f76bf16#publish)

Comment: I think it is definitly me, but after logging in and whoami. and running  `npm adduser --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=npm_tokenisasecretforyou --auth-type=legacy`  it returns with  `npm ERR! 404 Not Found - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=npm_***/-/user/org.couchdb.user:hoodedunicorn - Not found This package name is not valid, because 1. name can only contain URL-friendly characters`  after logging in with my credentials

Comment: Follow exactly as above. See, i've published [npm: vue-sfc-vite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-sfc-vite) and [github: @afzalsabbir/vue-sfc-vite](https://github.com/AfzalSabbir/vue-sfc-vite/pkgs/npm/vue-sfc-vite) just an hour ago.

Comment: I had it configured wrong in .npmrc. I can now install packages to Github and npmjs

Comment: With all due honesty I want to cast a vote, but I need 15 rep first. The repo I wanted to do it from is a bit borked. I did publish another repo and at first had the same issue. Then modified .npmrc file and it got published. I tried it again but it didn't work for the repo that is listed in the error msg.

Comment: You can click the Ckeck ✔️ button down to votes

Comment: Ah, apologies, I didn't see that check mark.